# React MUI background image not full screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite

I have a login page with a MUI Container component.

I want to set a background image to the whole page. I'm using react router.

I'm adding style to the outer div like this:

```
<div
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${coralBackground})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        width: '100vw',
        minHeight: '100vh',
      }}
    >
```

However, the page looks like this:

[image]

When I delete the MUI Container, it takes the whole space.

How do I get rid of the white part at the top and make the image take full space?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite likely to be because one of the following has some styles applied, outside the remit of React:

- The container the React DOM is rendered into.
- The `<body>` tag.
- Or the`<html>` tag.

Make sure to create some CSS such that all of these have `margin: 0; padding; 0`

Another possibility is in your base `index.html` you might have some element that is taking up space and needs to be removed.